# SQL Query with INNER Join is returning multiple duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

A view and a table, vwGrossEnergyYields and tblTurbineLayouts, are being combined with an inner join. Each table/view contains a field ProjectID and IsLive. Querying each by an example ProjectID and IsLive = 1 returns one row for each table/view:

```
SELECT [TurbineLayoutProjectID]
    ,[TurbineLayoutNumber]
    ,[Number]
    ,[ProjectID]
    
  FROM [GrossEnergy].[dbo].[vwGrossEnergyYields]
  
 WHERE [IsLive] = 1
 AND [ProjectID] IN
  (
    '2835'
  )
```

gives:

```
TurbineLayoutProjectID  TurbineLayoutNumber Number  ProjectID
2835    52  170 2835
```

and

```
SELECT  [Number]
    ,[ProjectID]
    
FROM [TurbineLayout].[dbo].[tblTurbineLayouts]
  
WHERE [IsLive] = 1
AND [ProjectID] IN
  (
    '2835'
  )
```

gives

```
Number  ProjectID
52  2835
```

A query is written, using INNER join, joining on TurbineLayoutNumber, intending to return only one row:

```
SELECT 
      [vwGrossEnergyYields].[TurbineLayoutProjectID] As TurbineLayoutProjID
      ,[vwGrossEnergyYields].[ProjectID]  As YieldProjID
      ,[vwGrossEnergyYields].[TurbineLayoutNumber]
      ,[vwGrossEnergyYields].[Number] As YieldNumber
  FROM [GrossEnergy].[dbo].[vwGrossEnergyYields]
  
  INNER JOIN [TurbineLayout].[dbo].[tblTurbineLayouts]
  ON [vwGrossEnergyYields].[TurbineLayoutNumber] = [tblTurbineLayouts].[Number]   
 
  WHERE [vwGrossEnergyYields].[IsLive] = 1
  AND [tblTurbineLayouts].[IsLive] = 1
  AND
  [vwGrossEnergyYields].[ProjectID] IN
  (
    '2835'
  )
```

This returns five rows:

```
TurbineLayoutProjID YieldProjID TurbineLayoutNumber YieldNumber
2835    2835    52  170
2835    2835    52  170
2835    2835    52  170
2835    2835    52  170
2835    2835    52  170
```

What is the error in the query that is causing it to return five rows instead of one?

Comment: Presumably you have a 1 to many relationship, so you are getting many rows. Considering you don't return any of the data from `tblTurbineLayouts`, perhaps what you actually want is an `EXISTS`?

Comment: You are not constraining the table on ProjectID in the joined query. When investigating these kind of problems, try Select * and see where the variation is

Comment: You have multiple records with `number = 52` in `tblTurbineLayouts`.

Comment: If you review the actual execution plan you'll see exactly where your 5 rows are coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, presumably you have a One-To-Many relationship, so you get 1 row for each related row.

As you aren't returning any data from the table `tblTurbineLayouts` then it seems an `EXISTS` would be a better solution:

```sql
SELECT GEY.TurbineLayoutProjectID AS TurbineLayoutProjID,
       GEY.ProjectID AS YieldProjID,
       GEY.TurbineLayoutNumber,
       GEY.Number AS YieldNumber
FROM GrossEnergy.dbo.vwGrossEnergyYields GEY
WHERE GEY.IsLive = 1
  AND GEY.ProjectID = '2835' --Change to =. Also should the value be an int, rather than a varchar(4)?
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TurbineLayout.dbo.tblTurbineLayouts TL
              WHERE TL.Number = GEY.TurbineLayoutNumber
                AND TL.IsLive = 1)
```

I also make some QoL changes, such as aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

The query is joined to a one to many relationship meaning -  [vwGrossEnergyYields].[TurbineLayoutNumber] = [tblTurbineLayouts].[Number]  - this join has multiple values in one of the tables - try joining with a different field or put the distinct keyword in your query for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  [vwGrossEnergyYields].[TurbineLayoutProjectID] As TurbineLayoutProjID
  ,[vwGrossEnergyYields].[ProjectID]  As YieldProjID
  ,[vwGrossEnergyYields].[TurbineLayoutNumber]
  ,[vwGrossEnergyYields].[Number] As YieldNumber
 FROM [GrossEnergy].[dbo].[vwGrossEnergyYields]

 INNER JOIN [TurbineLayout].[dbo].[tblTurbineLayouts]
 ON [vwGrossEnergyYields].[TurbineLayoutNumber] = [tblTurbineLayouts].[Number]   

 WHERE [vwGrossEnergyYields].[IsLive] = 1
 AND [tblTurbineLayouts].[IsLive] = 1
 AND
      [vwGrossEnergyYields].[ProjectID] IN
 (
     '2835'
 )
```

Comment: This'll give the right result, most likely, but I would suggest it'll be the least performant. `DISTINCT` is a very expensive operator.

Comment: True - but the query is small by the looks of it and the data returned wont affect the performance that much if the data is small - but at least if he cant join on another field this will give an option with fairly accurate data

Comment: But the "query" involves a view. You **assume** much without knowing anything about the view.